# Do we upvote correctness or usefulness?

Tags: discussion, voting

Take a quick look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929367/1961634) and, especially, the discussion. Please try not to consider the technical side of this question.

I am wondering who do you think is right: me, having downvoted the question because I think it is "not useful" or the answerer who claims it is "correct". I agree that it is correct and will work in the particular case, but I also think that outside of this very simple sscce it has no uses. Should I have upvoted the answer (it will work) or not (not really useful and rather bad practice).

tl;dr: do we upvote correctness or usefulness?

Comment: The question is bad, the answer isn't much better, but not because of the reasons you name. It's a perfectly legitimate solution to the given question, but only contains 2 lines of code and almost no explanation, which makes it useless. You downvote it because it makes no sense for optimizing performance by using multithreading, but _that's not what the question is about_, thus your reasoning makes no sense here. Anyways, if the answer would simply elaborate a bit more on the answer, explaining why it works here but makes not much sense in the general case, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @l4mpi how about posting that as an answer?

Comment: Because I already have and I've acknowledged l4mpi.

Comment: @TedTrippin I don't really want to discuss anything with you, but your *answer* really does not *answer* my question here, l4mpi's does. You are simply defending your original post on SE, which is actually not necessary because you've improved it already and I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: You should want to discuss, that's what this site is for. It's interesting that you're asking about upvoting here even though you **downvoted** my answer. However, the answer to your question here is useful=upvote, correct=dont vote, wrong=downvote. If an answer is **correct** but not good practice **in your opinion** just leave a comment. I only downvote if something is blatantly wrong.

Comment: @TedTrippin need I remind you that you called me names after a short discussion last time? In my book that disqualifies you as a conversation partner (unless you have ADHD or OCD or any other relevant D).

Comment: @Dariusz there's little sense in copypasting my comment into an answer, and I don't have the time or motivation to rewrite it into a full-fledged post. Feel free to write your own answer if you want to mark something as accepted.

Comment: @Dariusz there was no discussion, you just downvoted and made some inane comment. Look who's calling who names now ;)

Answer (score -2):

Since you've felt it necessary to raise this question I think I should share my side.

First of all, why would you say "Please try not to consider the technical side"? This was a technical question requiring a technical answer.

Was my answer correct? As you've admitted, yes it was correct.

Was it useful? As you've admitted, it was correct in this particular case, hence useful in this particular case.

Was it the best solution? We don't know. Based on the question it may well have been. There was not enough information to say otherwise. Even so, it was the fourth answer and no point in offering the same advice yet again. I was merely pointing out one solution that others had not.

You have jumped to too many conclusions about what the Op is looking for. And I believe wrongly so. The question asked demonstrates the Op has a lack of understanding about threads. Talking about optimisation, multiple threads and what "you" think is best practice is not needed nor asked for. I'm sure the Op will ask for this kind of help when they need it.

Comment: Don't want to nitpick here, but an answer (not just yours, any answer) isn't automatically useful just because it might be technically correct. Something that 'works' can be obsolete, promote bad practice, and generally not be useful in other ways. It's important to understand that. Also, if someone who's earned the privilege to voice their opinion on said usefulness casts a vote you disagree with, the proper response is to engage with them **constructively**. Not call them a troll and an idiot. Just saying.

Comment: Completely agree with you Clive. I never said "my answer is useful cus it works", I argued why my answer was possibly useful in this case. Dariuszs' argument was based on a context of his own choosing, not the Ops. You're right about my "troll" comment, that was uncalled for. I was incensed by Dariuszs' downvote and unuseful comment.